# Como validar se o TextField esta vazia?

Tags: ios, swift

Boa noite, meus caros

Estou com a dificuldade no seguinte, pretendo que o usuário receba um aviso quando a textfield estiver vazia e se o mesmo apertou no botão.

tentei com a condição if (textFiel.text == "") mais não deu certo, agradeço a nossa ajuda.

```
@IBAction func botton(_ sender: Any) {

    let celcius = Float(textFiel.text!)!
    let Fahrenheit:Float = (9 * celcius + 160) / 5
    label.text = "\(Fahrenheit)"


    if (textFiel.text == "") {
        label.text = "Por favor digite algo"
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outra sugestão é usar o comando *guard*:

```
@IBAction func botton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard !((textField.text ?? "").isEmpty) else {
        label.text = "Por favor digite algo"
        return
    }
    let celcius = NSString(string: textField.text!).floatValue
    let Fahrenheit:Float = (9 * celcius + 160) / 5
    label.text = "\(Fahrenheit)"
}
```

Comment: Bom dia, Edson da erro na sintaxe (!textFiel.isEmpty), diz que  Value of type 'UItextfiel' has no member ' isEmpry '

Parece que o erro esta a declaração de variáveis ou na construção do algoritmo, todas as sugestões me parece ótimas apenas não executam

Comment: Anselmo, corrigi o código agora esta correto.

Comment: Esta edição funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado Edson e a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: `guard textField.text?.isEmpty == false else {`

Comment: Para iOS 10+ UITextField  tem uma propriedade chamada `hasText` exatamente pra isso

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro você usar o `guard let`, ficar forçando `!` não é uma boa prática.

```
guard let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty else {
    return
}
```

Comment: iOS (10.0 and later) você pode usar a propriedade `hasText` **A Boolean value that indicates whether the text-entry objects has any text.**. `guard textField.hasText else { return }`

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está a comparar o `objecto` textFiel com a string vazia (""). O que pretende, é comparar se a propriedade `text` do objecto textFiel contém ou não algum texto.

Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
if (let texto = textFiel.text, !texto.isEmpty)
```

Talvez seja melhor efectuar esta validação antes de efectuar o cálculo:

```
@IBAction func botton(_ sender: Any) {

    if let texto = textFiel.text, !texto.isEmpty 
    {
        let celcius = Float(textFiel.text!)!
        let Fahrenheit:Float = (9 * celcius + 160) / 5
        label.text = "\(Fahrenheit)"
    else
    { 
        label.text = "Por favor digite algo"

    }
}
```

Veja o [exemplo](http://rextester.com/RNEGZ30299)

Comment: Não funcionou amigo, o console esta a dar o seguinte erro: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Veja a minha edição.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o ideia é verificar, além se o texto está vazio, se não é nil...

```
if textFiel.text != nil && !textFiel.text.isEmpty {
   label.text = "Por favor, digite algo"
}
```